# Export RDLC report to Excel without ReportViewer C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to export RDLC report to Excel without ReportViewer. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Below are my Steps:

1. Add New Item from Solution Explorer -- Reporting -- Report Wizard -- myReport.rdlc
2. Follow the wizard steps -- ConnectionString from web.config -- stored procedure as the source to create the report. I made 2 parameters, which is `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

   This is my stored procedure:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE mySP
       (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
   AS
   BEGIN
       SELECT * 
       FROM myTable 
       WHERE TheDate >= @StartDate AND TheDate <= @EndDate
   END
   ```
3. Add some fields for report
4. On the report designer -- Add 2 parameter, StartDate and EndDate.
5. Right Click on the designer -- Select Report Properties
6. On Variables section -- Add 2 parameters by Clicking on 'fx' button
7. Go to xsd file (myApp.xsd) -- on the tableadapter, right click then configure
8. Configuration of TableAdapter -- No change, I just click Next and Finish

Those are my steps to create the RDLC Report. I took the source from [Create RDLC Report in VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6bb76f/create-rdlc-report-in-vs-2010-and-sql-server-2008/)

The question is: How can I export the RDLC Report that I just design without using ReportViewer? I have one button on my webpage, let's say: 'Export to Excel'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType, encoding, extension;
        string filenameToSave = "test.xlsx";

        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        /*
         define here everything about your report: rdlc file, parameters, options etc.
        */ 

        FileStream newFile = new FileStream(filenameToSave, FileMode.Create);

        string renderFormat = (filenameToSave.EndsWith(".xlsx") ? "EXCELOPENXML" : "Excel");
        byte[] bytes = report.Render(renderFormat, null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
        newFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        newFile.Close();
```

Comment: Hi. Error on FileStream? What is that? The error said, the namespace could not be found

Comment: got it, Using System.IO;

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalReport.Render(), [here's how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms251839(v=vs.90).aspx)

note

- add assembly reference: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms (or install from nuget)
- then create a a report viewer instance:

`var viewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer( ... );`

Comment: The following code samples assume a Web form application with a ReportViewer control, a button, and a label. Would you help me to write the code please?

Comment: It also works without controls and buttons:
 - add assembly reference: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms (or install from nuget)
 - then create a a report viewer instance: var viewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer( ... );

Comment: error: One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified. On line: byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);